# Expo.io Always On Background Location Tracking with watchPositionAsync?

Tags: react-native, location, expo

Do compiled Expo.io React Native applications support "Always On" background location tracking, even when the app is not in use?

Answer (score 3):

Expo just implemented [Background Location](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/location/#background-location)

Instead of using the `watchPositionAsync` method, you will have to utilize `TaskManager.defineTask` method to register the background task out outside of the React event loop. Then, start the task with `Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. Quoting the "[Why not expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/why-not-expo.html)" page:

> Expo apps don’t support background code execution (running code when
>   the app is not foregrounded or the device is sleeping). This means you
>   cannot use background geolocation, play audio in the background,
>   handle push notifications in the background, and more. This is a work
>   in progress.

You will need to detach your app and add this behavior yourself, still doing so you lose some of the expo capabilities.

Comment: Moreno is right. However please do check back with expo in a while as this particular feature is under development and hopefully should be out soon!